# Smali: wide register index out of range

Tags: smali

I'm modifying an apk and I have added code to close after comparing dates.
I tried it in another application and it works perfectly. But I don't understand why it doesn't work with another apk.
The application that gives me an error is made in kotlin (in its internal structure there is a folder with that name).

`MainActivity.smali`

```
invoke-static {}, Ljava/lang/System;->currentTimeMillis()J

    move-result-wide p0

    const-wide p1, 0x1591f30c900L

    cmp-long p0, p0, p1

    if-lez p0, :cond_50

    const/4 v0, 0x1

    const-string v1, "End"

    invoke-static {p0, v1, v0}, Landroid/widget/Toast;->makeText(Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/CharSequence;I)Landroid/widget/Toast;

    move-result-object v0

    invoke-virtual {v0}, Landroid/widget/Toast;->show()V

    new-instance p0, Landroid/os/Handler;

    invoke-direct {p0}, Landroid/os/Handler;-><init>()V

    new-instance p0, Lcom/ball/gam/MainActivity$a;

    invoke-direct {p0, p0}, Lcom/ball/gam/MainActivity$a;-><init>(Lcom/ball/gam/MainActivity;)V

    const-wide/16 p1, 0x1770

    invoke-virtual {p0, p0, p1, p2}, Landroid/os/Handler;->postDelayed(Ljava/lang/Runnable;J)Z

    goto/16 :goto_50

    :cond_50
    :goto_50
    return-void
```

After opening the application you should compare the dates and in the case that the current date is greater than the one set, you should display the message toast End, wait 6 seconds and close the application.
Log after opening the application:

```
.gam.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle): [0xFFFFFFFF] wide register index out of range (10+1 >= 11) (declaration of com/ball/gam/MainActivity' appears in /data/app/com.ball.gamex-1/base.apk
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. Could you upload your error? Could you edit your post? (Some code is shown as text)

Comment: Hello @DavidGarcíaBodego do you speak spanish?

Comment: Error is on : move-result-wide p0 ; const-wide p1, 0x1591f30c900L;  cmp-long p0, p0, p1 ; if-lez p0, :cond_50 ; and  const-wide/16 p1, 0x1770 ;   invoke-virtual {p0, p0, p1, p2}, Landroid/os/Handler;->postDelayed(Ljava/lang/Runnable;J)Z

Comment: Please post your onCreate method.